# Android Studio set variable name according to the google docs

Tags: android, android-studio

According to the google code style docs class member variables name started with a "m" and for static field name started with a "s" at the start.

In Android Studio when we want to create a class member variable, it suggest a name like class name without "m". so we have to add "m" and change second letter to upper case.

[image: Android studio show this]

so how can I force to android studio to named variable name with a "m" at the start or "s" for static fields and for other types.

Or how can I edit code complete dialog fields.

Android studio suggest this:

> ClassA classA;

Goolge docs suggest this:

> ClassA mClassA;

Comment: I think naming Conventions should be followed according to language. So if you coding in java then you should follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). To add prefix you can set it from Setting.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to setting and search for code and below is the screen which will appear and allows you to change your prefix for static or member variables.

[image]